# PouchDB - IN Clause

Tags: pouchdb

How can I efficiently read multiple documents from PouchDB when I have their IDs?

I try AllDocs

```
db.allDocs({
  keys: ['givenId1','givenId2',...,'givenId100'],
});
```

It is too slow , When I have 10000 docs in database and want read 100 keys with `include_docs=false` , it take about 8 seconds

I use `websql` adaptor

Answer (score 0):

The [PouchDb docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch) do warn of performance issues using AllDocs and "keys". I would suggest a couple of things to try that could improve performance:

(1) Try *not* using a specific adaptor - WebSQL may not be the best choice for your platform.

(2) Define an index in a design document and use a map/reduce query to read the documents. The documentation is [here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) and has some examples to get you started if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: Can you past a quote ,Where PouchDb docs warn of performance issues using AllDocs and "keys"? I cannot find it

Comment: You are not using startkey/endkey and there is a note about pagination and performance in that case: 

"Notes: For pagination, options.limit and options.skip are also available, but the same performance concerns as in CouchDB apply. Use the startkey/endkey pattern instead." but I am not sure if that is relevant to you.

In a big dataset AllDocs will still read everything even though you specify the keys you want. An index and map/reduce might be more efficient and is not difficult to implement, so if I were you I would try it to see if it improves things.

Comment: is map/reduce scan whole database?

Comment: Can you show me how can I create map reduce to fetch all documents that _id is included in an array , I want to get all once

Comment: Indexes that are saved to design documents do not scan the whole database. You write an "emit" that defines what the index contains and you only need to emit some documents. For example, if you have a field called "colour" in your documents you could say if (doc.colour == "red") emit (doc.colour). If you use the "include_docs" option the rest of the document is also available to you (as well as the colour field). There are better notes and examples here:  https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database